# US unemployment data release date

Tags: data-request, federal-reserve, unemployment

Using the CSV file provided by [St. Louis Fed](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/UNRATE) (which is based on the data series [LNS14000000](https://data.bls.gov/timeseries/LNS14000000) from the Bureau of Labor Statistics) I noticed that the date is **always the first day of each month** for the unemployment rate, i.e. for May 1957 it is `1957-05-01` and so on. Because BLS currently [will announce the data](https://www.bls.gov/cps/) for June 2018 on the **6th** of July, I doubt that the CSV file is correct. Where can I find the accurate historic release dates for the unemployment rates?

Answer (score 1):

After some more intensive (4 mins) googling I found it on the [BLS](https://www.bls.gov/schedule/news_release/empsit.htm) website.

Comment: Could you mark the question as answered?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to economics.SE. This answer could be improved by reciting the solution in the text of the answer, rather than just providing a link. You could copy and paste in quotes. This follows the discussion found here: https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/reference-only-answers